# Bash Script logrotation and compressing

Tags: shell-script

i need to create a bash script to rotate and compress system log file in ubuntu based on log size with max size 1Mbyte

Answer (score 1):

Use the `logrotate` tool.  It comes with Ubuntu.  No need to write your own.  You could have a config file (e.g. `mylog`) in the `/etc/logrotate.d` directory:

```
/path/to/my/log/file {
    rotate 4
    missingok
    size 1M
    compress
}
```

The above tells the `logrotate` utility to rotate the log file, `/path/to/my/log/file`.  It will keep 4 backups.  If it is missing, that's ok.  Rotate if the size of the log file exceeds 1M, and compress the backup.

There are a ton of other options.  Check the man page for more info on what can go into the `logrotate` configuration file.

Comment: Updated with an example.